# How to define width of the column in the table dynamically

Tags: html, css, angular

> [Class.width]="header.width" This doesn't work.How else can I achieve
> a dyanamically set width of the each column of the table.

**app.component.html**

```
<th class="name-center head-color " *ngFor="let header of tableHeader;let headIndex=index" [class.width]="header.width"
    >{{header.value}}</th>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
this.tableHeader=[{"name":"sno","value":"S.No","width":"5%"},
{"name":"training","value":"Training","width":"35%"},
{"name":"skill","value":"Skill","width":"20%"},
{"name":"applicableProficiency","value":"Applicable proficiency","width":"20%"},
{"name":"trainingAction","value":"Training Action","width":"20%"}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let header of tableHeader;let headIndex=index">
    <th class="name-center head-color " [ngStyle]="{'width': header.width}">{{header.value}}</th>
</ng-container>
```

Or

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let header of tableHeader;let headIndex=index">
    <th class="name-center head-color " [style.width]="header.width">{{header.value}}</th>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a container to keep a reference to your tableHeader item and set accordingly the desired width:

```
<table width="100%" border=1>
    <tr>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let header of tableHeader;let headIndex=index">
            <th class="name-center head-color " [width]="header.width">{{header.value}}</th>
        </ng-container>
    </tr>

</table>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-angular-tutorial-app-vzwsde?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample%2Fexample.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

angular dont watch on object prop in array of objects. for making that you want u must reinit array: this.tableHeade = Array.from(this.tableHeade) to launch redraw OR on some action (when data changed) u can tell component to redraw: ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()